# Shimano hydraulic brake config; R8020 levers paired with R8170 calipers?

Tags: hydraulic

Good Day All:

This winter I am "kitting out" a carbon fibre frameset from Pursuit Cycles.
I have elected to go with mech shifting, 11sp Ultegra R8000, and hydraulic braking.
I have on hand a pair of unused R8020 levers and would like to pair them with the newer R8170 calipers. Is there anyone here who has had real experience with such a pairing?
All insights appreciated. I have yet to find a definitive answer on this....
VTY, David

Answer (score 5):

I've lost track of which combinations I have and haven't seen that are sanctioned by the official charts, but yours is on there:

[image]

Comment: That's very kind of you! Many thanks.......really appreciated!